# how can i replace some specif text in GWT TextArea

Tags: gwt

I am trying to replace some specific word or could be at some specific index(whichever is easier) . With some new word.

I am not able to find a solution for entering some text inside my textarea at some specific index .

Is there anyway

thanks

For example  . In my textArea   this is a text :   "Hello, This is testing"
Now I just want to insert testing12  instead of testing .

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
myTextArea.setValue(myTextArea.getValue().replace(myTextArea.getSelectedText(), "new text"));
```

Comment: there is one issue with this approach , if for example , the selected text is "test" then when i replace it , It replaces all "test" in my text area , where as i just wanted to replace the selected one .. Any idea

Comment: may be I can get the index of selectedText and then put a new word at that index, but not sure how to place a new word at some specific index.

Comment: Look at the documentation for TextArea widget. It lists methods you can use to find the start and end index of a selected text.

Comment: I have the start/end index , What i can find is how I will put the new text on that index, if u can please give an idea

Comment: If you know start and end, you can do text.substring(0,start) + " new text" + text.substring(end).